# Expose parts of a private GitLab repository to a public GitLab repository

Tags: git, gitlab

Our development team has been working on a private repository in GitLab. We have a master and develop branch, along with some feature branches, and a release branch.

We have decided to make the project open source. To this end, we created a new public repository in GitLab. Ideally, we want to find an automated way to synchronize the public with the private GitLab repository. The public repository should contain a single branch *master*, which is a mirror of the *release* branch from the private GitLab repository. Is there an automated way of doing this?

As a temporary solution, we mirrored the contents of the private repository into the public one. However, by doing so we expose the history (including secrets we do not want share).

Comment: You could prepare a CI definition pushing a specific (prepared, as you want to control the commit history as you said) branch to your public remote.

Comment: Thanks @djuarez, I will give it a try!